# Polymer 1.x: Using app-drawer-layout

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, app-elements

[Here is my jsBin](http://jsbin.com/kamusideji/1/edit?html,output). I want to render [the code example contained here in the documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/app-layout?active=app-drawer-layout) (in the 4th section of sample code).

```
<app-drawer-layout>
  <app-drawer>
    drawer-content
  </app-drawer>
  <app-header-layout>
    <app-header>
      <app-toolbar>
        <paper-icon-button icon="menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
        <div main-title>App name</div>
      </app-toolbar>
    </app-header>

    main content

  </app-header-layout>
</app-drawer-layout>
```

I expect to see following three sections:

1. the drawer panel to the left,
2. the app name and menu `paper-icon-button`,
3. the main content section.

Instead, I only see the sections numbered 1 and 3; and not number 2.

I also expect to see the drawer panel begin in a closed state and toggle when the non existent menu button is clicked. Instead, the drawer panel begins in the open state.

How can I achieve the desired behavior?

[Link to jsBin](http://jsbin.com/kamusideji/1/edit?html,output)

http://jsbin.com/kamusideji/1/edit?html,output

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="iron-icon/iron-icon.html" rel="import">
  <link href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html" rel="import">
  <link href="app-layout/app-drawer/app-drawer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="app-layout/app-drawer-layout/app-drawer-layout.html" rel="import">
  <link href="app-layout/app-header-layout/app-header-layout.html" rel="import">
  <link href="app-layout/app-header/app-header.html" rel="import">
  <link href="app-layout/app-toolbar/app-toolbar.html" rel="import">
</head>
<body>

<dom-module id="x-element">

<template>
  <style></style>

<app-drawer-layout>
  <app-drawer>
    drawer-content
  </app-drawer>
  <app-header-layout>
    <app-header>
      <app-toolbar>
        <paper-icon-button icon="menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
        <div main-title>App name</div>
      </app-toolbar>
    </app-header>

    main content

  </app-header-layout>
</app-drawer-layout>

</template>

<script>
  (function(){
    Polymer({
      is: "x-element",
      properties: {},
    });
  })();
</script>

</dom-module>

<x-element></x-element>

</body>
```

Edit 1

If you open the <kbd>Console</kbd> [tab in the jsBin](http://jsbin.com/kamusideji/1/edit?html,output), it sort of works!? But stops working after you close the console tab??!! WTF? Can someone please clarify what is happening? Is this a bug?

Edit 2

No, it's not a bug. The behavior described in Edit was caused by a change in the state of the `media query`: the screen size switched to `narrow`. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `force-narrow` attribute to the `<app-drawer-layout>` element as follows:

```
<app-drawer-layout force-narrow>
```

[Here is the jsBin](http://jsbin.com/qevojojalo/1/edit?html,output).

http://jsbin.com/qevojojalo/1/edit?html,output

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="iron-icon/iron-icon.html" rel="import">
  <link href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html" rel="import">
  <link href="app-layout/app-drawer/app-drawer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="app-layout/app-drawer-layout/app-drawer-layout.html" rel="import">
  <link href="app-layout/app-header-layout/app-header-layout.html" rel="import">
  <link href="app-layout/app-header/app-header.html" rel="import">
  <link href="app-layout/app-toolbar/app-toolbar.html" rel="import">
</head>
<body>

<dom-module id="x-element">

<template>
  <style></style>

<app-drawer-layout force-narrow>
  <app-drawer>
    drawer-content
  </app-drawer>
  <app-header-layout>
    <app-header>
      <app-toolbar>
        <paper-icon-button icon="menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
        <div main-title>App name</div>
      </app-toolbar>
    </app-header>

    main content

  </app-header-layout>
</app-drawer-layout>

</template>

<script>
  (function(){
    Polymer({
      is: "x-element",
      properties: {},
    });
  })();
</script>

</dom-module>

<x-element></x-element>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `has-scrolling-region` to `app-header-layout` and either `force-narrow` or `fullbleed` to `<app-drawer-layout>` to make it work as you want. If not, the original rending of the header put it under the drawer.

I would use:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
    <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
    <link href="iron-icon/iron-icon.html" rel="import">
    <link href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html" rel="import">
    <link href="paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html" rel="import">
    <link href="app-layout/app-drawer/app-drawer.html" rel="import">
    <link href="app-layout/app-drawer-layout/app-drawer-layout.html" rel="import">
    <link href="app-layout/app-header-layout/app-header-layout.html" rel="import">
    <link href="app-layout/app-header/app-header.html" rel="import">
    <link href="app-layout/app-toolbar/app-toolbar.html" rel="import">
  </head>
  <body>

  <dom-module id="x-element">

    <template>
      <style>
      </style>

    <app-drawer-layout fullbleed>
      <app-drawer>
        drawer-content
      </app-drawer>
      <app-header-layout  has-scrolling-region>
        <app-header  condenses reveals effects="waterfall">
          <app-toolbar>
            <paper-icon-button icon="menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
            <div main-title>App name</div>
          </app-toolbar>
        </app-header>

        main content

      </app-header-layout>
    </app-drawer-layout>

    </template>

    <script>
      (function(){
        Polymer({
          is: "x-element",
          properties: {},
        });
      })();
    </script>

  </dom-module>

  <x-element></x-element>

  </body>
</html>
```

Example here: http://jsbin.com/pilogib/1/edit?html,output